# Java Regex won't match

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a program that will return all the text between `\begin{theorem}` and `\end{theorem}` and between `\begin{proof}` and `\end{proof}`.

It seems natural to use regex's, but because there are a lot of potential metacharacters, they will need to be escaped.

Here's the code I have written:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class LatexTheoremProofExtractor {

    // This is the LaTeX source that will be processed
    private String source = null;

    // These are the list of theorems and proofs that are extracted, respectively 
    private ArrayList<String> theorems = null;
    private ArrayList<String> proofs = null;

    // These are the patterns to match theorems and proofs, respectively 
    private static final Pattern THEOREM_REGEX = Pattern.compile("\\begin\\{theorem\\}(.+?)\\end\\{theorem\\}");
    private static final Pattern PROOF_REGEX = Pattern.compile("\\begin\\{proof\\}(.+?)\\end\\{proof\\}");

    LatexTheoremProofExtractor(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public void parse() {
        extractEntity("theorem");
        extractEntity("proof");
    }

    private void extractTheorems() {
        if(theorems != null) {
            return;
        }

        theorems = new ArrayList<String>();

        final Matcher matcher = THEOREM_REGEX.matcher(source);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            theorems.add(new String(matcher.group(1)));
        }   
    }

    private void extractProofs() {
        if(proofs != null) {
            return;
        }

        proofs = new ArrayList<String>();

        final Matcher matcher = PROOF_REGEX.matcher(source);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            proofs.add(new String(matcher.group(1)));
        }       
    }

    private void extractEntity(final String entity) {   
        if(entity.equals("theorem")) {
            extractTheorems();
        } else if(entity.equals("proof")) {
            extractProofs();
        } else {
            // TODO: Throw an exception or something
        }       
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getTheorems() {
        return theorems;
    }

}
```

and below is my test that fails

```
@Test 
public void testTheoremExtractor() {
    String source = "\\begin\\{theorem\\} Hello, World! \\end\\{theorem\\}";
    LatexTheoremProofExtractor extractor = new LatexTheoremProofExtractor(source);
    extractor.parse();
    ArrayList<String> theorems = extractor.getTheorems();
    assertEquals(theorems.get(0).trim(), "Hello, World!");
}
```

Clearly my test suggests I'd like there to only be one match in this test, and it should be "Hello, World!" (post trimming).

Currently `theorems` is an empty, non-`null` array. Thus my `Matcher`s aren't matching the pattern. Can anyone help me understand why?

Thanks,
erip

Comment: Use ``\\\\`` to match one ``\``.

Comment: @stribizhev I made the change but it gives me the same result - size is 0.

Comment: if the text is constant as you said `\begin{theorem}`, etc.. I don't think you need regex for that, why don't you just split the data according to those delimiters? or by using `indexof()`

Comment: @LiranBo Pretty sure `String#split` uses `Pattern`/`Matcher` under the hood.

Comment: Have a look at [this code](http://ideone.com/Z1p64k), it works. Look at the 2 updated regexes in your extractor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the update you need to make to your code - the 2 regexes in the extractor method should be changed to

```
private static final Pattern THEOREM_REGEX = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("\\begin\\{theorem\\}") + "(.+?)" + Pattern.quote("\\end\\{theorem\\}"));
private static final Pattern PROOF_REGEX = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("\\begin\\{proof\\}") + "(.+?)" + Pattern.quote("\\end\\{proof\\}"));
```

The result will be "Hello, World!". [See IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Z1p64k).

The string you have is actually `\begin\{theorem\} Hello, World! \end\{theorem\}`. The literal backslashes in Java strings are doubled and when you need to match a literal backslash in Java with a regex, you need to use `\\\\`. To avoid the [backslash hell](https://tudorbarbu.ninja/backslash-hell/), `Pattern.quote` can be of help that will tell the regex to treat all the subpattern inside it as a literal.

More details about `Pattern.quote` can be found in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)):

> Returns a literal pattern `String` for the specified `String`.
>   This method produces a `String` that can be used to create a `Pattern` that would match the string `s` as if it were a literal pattern.
>
> Metacharacters or escape sequences in the input sequence will be given no special meaning.

Comment: I added more fun links and explanations. Actually, you can use `\\Q` and `\\E` instead, but it is important to apply that to both the regexps.

Answer (score 0):

Your first regex needs to be:

```
Pattern THEOREM_REGEX = Pattern.compile("\\\\begin\\\\\\{theorem\\\\\\}(.+?)\\\\end\\\\\\{theorem\\\\\\}");
```

as you're trying to match a backslash that requires **\\\\** in your regex.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an error in your test code that the other answers don't address.  You create the test string like this:

```
String source = "\\begin\\{theorem\\} Hello, World! \\end\\{theorem\\}";
```

...but in the text you say the source string is supposed to be:

```
\begin{theorem} Hello, World! \end{theorem}
```

If that's true, the string literal should be:

```
"\\begin{theorem} Hello, World! \\end{theorem}"
```

To create the regex, you would use:

```
Pattern.quote("\\begin{theorem}") + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote("\\end{theorem}")
```

...or escape it manually:

```
"\\\\begin\\{theorem\\}(.*?)\\\end\\{theorem\\}"
```